# Messy figure placement... thoughts?

Tags: graphics, environments

I've been struggling with figure placement a lot lately, mostly on how to use the parameters h, t, !, H, and so on... The question is not how to use properly these parameters, but how to keep them from compiling a messy document. Check this for example:

```
\vspace{\baselineskip}
{\bold Faixa de variação dos parâmetros do DOE}

Dutos primários: 475mm-675mm com passos de 22mm.

Duto pós-união: 325mm-525mm com passos de 22mm.

Os {\italic flowsplits} adicionam {\bold 75mm} para cada valor dos eixos dos gráficos.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, center]{box_42dualB}
    \caption{Reformulação do {\italic plenum/resonator box} para configuração de duas entradas e duas saídas. \label{fig:box_42dualB}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{flushleft}
    {\bold 3000RPM}
\end{flushleft}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, center]{42Bebrnmfcs3000}
    \caption{Massa queimada no início do ciclo em função do comprimento dos primários e secundários - 3000rpm \label{fig:42Bebrnmfcs3000}}

\begin{flushright}
    {\bold 4000RPM}
\end{flushright}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, center]{42Bebrnmfcs4000}
    \caption{Massa queimada no início do ciclo em função do comprimento dos primários e secundários - 4000rpm \label{fig:42Bebrnmfcs4000}}
\end{multicols}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, center]{conc42DualB}
    \caption{Estrutura do modelo computacional para estudo sobre o conceito 4-2 Dual B \label{fig:conc42DualB}}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{flushleft}
    {\bold 5000RPM}
\end{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, center]{42Bebrnmfcs5000}
    \caption{Massa queimada no início do ciclo em função do comprimento dos primários e secundários - 5000rpm \label{fig:42Bebrnmfcs5000}}

\begin{flushright}
    {\bold 6000RPM}
\end{flushright}    
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, center]{42Bebrnmfcs6000}
    \caption{Massa queimada no início do ciclo em função do comprimento dos primários e secundários - 6000rpm \label{fig:42Bebrnmfcs6000}}
\end{multicols}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering

    \begin{tabular}{ ||c|c|c|c|c|| }
    \hline
    {\bold Comprimento} & {\bold Torque} & {\bold Eff Volumétrica} & {\bold bHP} & {\bold ebrnmfcs}\\
    \hline
    Xmm \& Xmm & X Nm & X & X hp & X\% \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

\caption{Resultados do estudo preliminar de otimização do conceito 4-2 Dual B em 4000rpm}    \label{tab:DOE42dB}
\end{table}


\subsubsection{Definição dos dutos principais}


Tendo dados que representam individualmente os conceitos, estes agora serão equiparados para identificar e escolher a melhor alternativa. Antes que isto seja feito, devemos evidenciar os objetivos relacionados à performance que guiam este projeto, para que a escolha mais apropriada seja tomada a seguir.

Na seção {\bold \ref{sec:summaryObj} - Sumário de requisitos técnicos estabelecidos}, são listados como requisitos técnicos principais, entre outros:
```

Produces...

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

The root of all evil is when I **have to** use 'H'. Using h, h!, t, b or the like will usually push the surplus of images way ahead in the document - sometimes it just place it all in the last page of the chapter. The main problem, I suppose, is having too many images altogether. This is a section of my report that I'm just presenting more results than theorizing upon - I just present the simulated data and discuss it briefly. There's not much I can do in terms of adding text to it - and shouldn't.

All that I really need is an advice on how to place these images without overfulls such as the one happening on the second page I'm posting here. I cannot allow these images to be placed beyond this scope because it would be misleading to the reader since I'm presenting several different concepts - having a concept's content merged into the space dedicated to another one is not desirable. What would be the ideal arragement for this?

Comment: This is heavily dependent on your document content, of which you've provided very little. Moreover, you're not allowing the content to *float* (as a result of using the `[H]` float specifier). See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

Comment: It is hard to comment on your document fragment as it can not be run to see any issues and uses many commands that are not defined by default such as `\bold` and `\italic`  (why not use teh standard font commands?)  however based on your comments note that an option such as `[h]` increases the probability that that float and all following ones go to the end of a chapter as it means not-t, not-b, not-p so stops latex putting the figure at the top of a page, the bottom of a page or on a page of figures. that does not leave many places where it is allowed to go.

Comment: In particular, do share with us which document class you use, what the paper size is (A4?, US Letter?, Something else?), how wide the margins are, which font you use, and what the main font size is.

Comment: judging from what appears to be the page number (49) on the first page shown, there simply isn't room for both "levels" of figures on the second page.

Comment: The evil is use `[H]` or `[h]` alone. I think that I have never found a good reason to be so restrictive in any serious document. If you have a lot of images and little text our best option is  relax a bit the LaTeX rules (increase `\topfraction`, increase counters as `topnumber`, etc.) and left as many options as possible to each figure.  Try with `[!tbph]` at least until the very last version, then change it as needed, if necessary. The link suggested by Werner is a must to understand float placement.

Comment: I would use [p] or [tp!] for most of these.  As soon as you have enough to fill a page, they should show up, or one can use \afterpage{\clearpage} (afterpage package) to force the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You've provided very little information regarding important document parameters (paper size, size of text block, document class, etc), so it's not possible to give very specific suggestions. The two broadest suggestions I can make are:

- Load the `placeins` package and insert `\FloatBarrier` instructions to keep floats from wandering off too far to the back of the document.
- Don't use a `multicols` environment to place two smaller figures side by side; instead, use two `minipage` environments, separated by `\hfill`.
- Don't use `[H]` placement specifiers. If you feel like you simply must provide placement specifiers, use `[ht!]`.

By the way, how are `\bold` and `\italic` defined? Any reason for not using `\bfseries` and `\itshape`?

Here's an attempt to come up with a compilable example that implements these ideas.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % select font family 
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % is this language setting correct?
\usepackage[hmargin=4cm,vmargin=3cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page size parameters

\usepackage{placeins} % for "\FloatBarrier" macro

%% Just for this example:
\usepackage{chngcntr} % for \counterwithin macro
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\setcounter{section}{4}
\setcounter{subsection}{3} % ?
\setcounter{figure}{38} 
\let\bold\bfseries  %% ?
\let\italic\itshape %% ?
% use a sans-serif font as the main body font
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault 

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[ht!]
% do the following lines belong together with the graph?
{\bold Faixa de variação dos parâmetros do DOE}

Dutos primários: 475mm--675mm com passos de 22mm.

Duto pós-união: 325mm--525mm com passos de 22mm.

Os {\italic flowsplits} adicionam {\bold 75mm} para cada valor dos eixos dos gráficos.

\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight]{box_42dualB}
\caption{Reformulação do {\italic plenum\slash resonator box} para configuração de duas entradas e duas saídas. \label{fig:box_42dualB}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{minipage}{0.475\textwidth}
{\bold 3000RPM}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{42Bebrnmfcs3000}
\caption{Massa queimada no início do ciclo em função do comprimento dos primários e secundários--3000rpm \label{fig:42Bebrnmfcs3000}}
\end{minipage}% % no blank line
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.475\textwidth}
\raggedleft{\bold 4000RPM}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{42Bebrnmfcs4000}
\caption{Massa queimada no início do ciclo em função do comprimento dos primários e secundários--4000rpm \label{fig:42Bebrnmfcs4000}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.7\textheight]{conc42DualB}
\caption{Estrutura do modelo computacional para estudo sobre o conceito 4-2 Dual~B}
\label{fig:conc42DualB}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{minipage}{0.475\textwidth}
{\bold 5000RPM}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{42Bebrnmfcs5000}
\caption{Massa queimada no início do ciclo em função do comprimento dos primários e secundários--5000rpm \label{fig:42Bebrnmfcs5000}}
\end{minipage}% % no blank line
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.475\textwidth}
\raggedleft{\bold 6000RPM}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{42Bebrnmfcs6000}
\caption{Massa queimada no início do ciclo em função do comprimento dos primários e secundários--6000rpm \label{fig:42Bebrnmfcs6000}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\FloatBarrier  % make sure the "table" comes after the 6 "figure" environments

\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % optional, for a less cramped "look"
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ ||c|c|c|c|c|| }
    \hline
    {\bold Comprimento} & {\bold Torque} & {\bold Eff Volumétrica} & {\bold bHP} & {\bold ebrnmfcs}\\
    \hline
    Xmm \& Xmm & X Nm & X & X hp & X\% \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Resultados do estudo preliminar de otimização do conceito 4-2 Dual~B em 4000rpm}    \label{tab:DOE42dB}
\end{table}

\subsubsection{Definição dos dutos principais}

Tendo dados que representam individualmente os conceitos, estes agora serão equiparados para identificar e escolher a melhor alternativa. Antes que isto seja feito, devemos evidenciar os objetivos relacionados à performance que guiam este projeto, para que a escolha mais apropriada seja tomada a seguir.

Na seção {\bold \ref{sec:summaryObj}--Sumário de requisitos técnicos estabelecidos}, são listados como requisitos técnicos principais, entre outros: \dots

\end{document}
```